# d3 way to something like matlabs plot3

Tags: d3.js, line-plot

I'm sure d3 can do something like matlabs [plot3](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35262-matlab-plot-gallery-line-plot-3d/content/html/Line_Plot_3D.html)!
Multi-Series Line charts I have somewhat figured out by now, but as my lines tend to not change drastically over time (yes, 3rd axis would be time) multi-series is not of much use there, esp. with 10+ lines, say.

I have more data connected to some points of some lines - which I have right now accessible via tooltips with urls. And I quite like it. But If anyone would has a nicer idea for 2D, I'm all ears.

Comment: This may help http://roadtolarissa.com/population-division/

Comment: Thx @In code veritas - I also found http://charts.animateddata.co.uk/uktemperaturelines/ , though both not that straight forward to understand for me